# How to apply css in jQuery on variable that is in loop?

Tags: php, jquery, css, variables, foreach

Hello guys I search alot but find nothing regarding my problem.
I have one foreach loop in that i have one anchor tag and that will be changed according to my `ifelse` condition.
Now I want to change color of each if else condition in that. Please help me to do.My code is within jQuery script.

```
for(var j=0;j<arrayData.length;j++){
  var country = "";
  if(arrayData[j].key=="40"){
    country = "UK";
  }else if(arrayData[j].key=="41"){
    country = "INDIA";
  }else if(arrayData[j].key=="47"){
    country = "POLAND";
  }else{
    country = "GERMANY";
  }
  check+='<a class="btn btn-success" href="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/'+arrayData[j].value+'">'+country+
                    '</a>|';
}
check +='</td></tr>';
```

Comment: you want to update the css of your <a> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append it on the html string.

```
for(var j=0;j<arrayData.length;j++){
   var country = "";
   var color = "";
   if(arrayData[j].key=="40"){
       country = "UK";
       color = "red";
   }else if(arrayData[j].key=="41"){
       country = "INDIA";
       color = "orange";
   }else  if(arrayData[j].key=="47"){
       country = "POLAND";
       color = "yellow";
   }else{
        country = "GERMANY";
       color = "green";
   }

   check+='<a class="btn btn-success" style="background-color:' + color  + ';" href="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/'+arrayData[j].value+'">'+country+
                    '</a>|';
}

 check +='</td></tr>';
```

---

**Other option:** You can also add class to `<a>` tag.

Like `<a class="color-red">`

CSS:

```
.color-red {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.Your code is working.But i want to change my anchor tags color. your code changes color of NAMES onto it

Comment: Ohh.. then we change the code from `color` to `background-color`. Please see my updated answer @amitsutar